# How much power does a GPU actually use when only doing PCIe I/O, or only compute?

Tags: measurement, memory, power-consumption, gpu

<sub>I *hope* this is the right sight to ask such a question, if not please be kind and direct me elsewhere.</sub>

I have some discrete GPU with a TDP figure of X watts. Now, sometimes the GPU does

- Only computation (executing kernels)
- Only PCIe transfers (host-to-device or device-to-host copying, or both kinds of transfer on certain cards),
- Both compute and PCIe I/O
- Idling

How much of the stated TDP can I expect the card to use in each of these scenarios?

**Notes:**

- If your answer is manufacturer-specific and GPU generation-specific, I'm interested in NVidia Kepler 700 series and NVidia Maxwell (705, or the 900 series). Information about other cards will also be appreciated.
- If the answer is "it depends", typical figures under assumptions are also good.

Comment: Links to information about the specific cards would be useful, to save others searching.

Comment: @David: Do you mean that as a comment to me, or to people who intend to answer?

Comment: Build or buy a PCIe extension slot. Cut into the power and ground rails. Hook up an ammeter or killawatt or similar device. Watch it go and Take notes. That's your answer.

Comment: @Passerby: 1. Make that an answer? 2. Do I really need an extension slot? Can't I "cut into the rails" using my board as-is? (Sorry, I'm a Comp Sci critter, not an electronics esquire).

Comment: Yes, you could sacrifice a motherboard. I assumed that most wouldn't want to do that. An extension board/cable wouldn't be too expensive on ebay though.

Answer (score 1):

In the lack of manufacturer disclosure (most consumers of pcie modular cards don't care about power usage, though embedded pcie devices might in order to beat maximum power draw numbers in the nano board  or thin client market), emperical testing is required.

This can be done by identifying the power rails (PCIe pin out), and interfacing an ammeter inbetween them. For most purposes, pcie has multiple 12V and GND pins, so you might need multiple ammeters. Cheaper ammeters will average the current use out, good enough for most purposes. (Ex, showing 200mA at 12V, over 10 minutes with a steady load of 10% would mean 0.6 W average).  A scope or logging output would allow graphing for more detail.

You could hack a motherboard up to access the traces, but a spare extension card (riser or dual adapter) or cable would be useful if you didn't want to take a dremel and soldering iron to a full board.

Comment: 1. What would you recommend as the method for fastening the ammeter connectors to the PCIe pins? 2. Don't ammeters typically show just the last measurement taken rather than averaging over a longer period of time?

Comment: I would solder a wire to a jack or terminal block or a pair of headers. When not in use, you can close it with a jumper or wire. And no, most ammeters I seen are live, not snapshot.

Comment: Another question. My card has a separate power connector... so, do I do $P = P_1 + P_2 = (I_1 x V_1) + (I_2 x V_2)$?

Answer (score 0):

Realistically the card will only use marginal amounts of power while doing PCIe IO. The actual amount varies between cards, but likely not much above the minimal TDP (look at spec sheets for this value).

Running kernels is a different story. Assuming your kernel uses nearly 100% of the core, the card will be using its full TDP. The kernels use the same processor on the card, it just doesn't create video output.

Comment: I don't think I've found minimal TDP figures anywhere... see, for example: http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-780/specifications

Comment: Do you have a specific card you're looking at? Sometimes the actual manufacturer publishes the info, not Nvidia.

Comment: It's an NVidia card :-(

Comment: It's not actually. Nvidia only manufactures chips. There's an actual brand name somewhere on the card, something like EGVA, ASUS, or Gigabyte

Comment: Ah, right you are. It's MSI.

Comment: Ok. According to some reviews of the card, average idle is about 10 watts. At full usage, it'll get up to about 264 watts.

Comment: Umm, I only gave that model as an example; do you suppose you could like to such reviews? Anyway, mine is GTX 780 Ti. Also, if a "marginal amount" of power is used when doing I/O - is it idle + 0.1 * (max - idle)? 0.05? less?